# Cancelling control of KeyBoard about scroll of ScrollView?

Tags: wpf

`Key.Down，Key.Up`. That can control scroll of `ScrollView`. Please, how to cancel control?

Comment: Please be a little more specific.For Which control are you trying to do this.Is it a list control or a normal window ?

Answer (score 1):

The ScrollViewer react to keyboard keys - it have the focus.If you want to cancel that behaviour,try setting `Focusable="False"` for your Scrollviewer

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that the information you provide is a bit less, but for as far as I get it, you want to turn off keyboard usage?

I'm not sure if there's a function to turn off the keyboard, but what you can do, is add a keylistener. All keypresses can be ignored, or configured the way you want to.

For an example of keylisteners, you can check this site, which is a topic about C# keylisteners:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f83d3d71-ea3e-4b18-a610-30a91fae060e/

Comment: I think biju his solution works better in your situation, and you can program how the scrolling should go.